# Hard drive not recognized

Tags: hard-drive

I'm dealing with an issue with my7 wife's computer. It goes through not seeing a hard drive that is connected. I've tried different SATA cables and several SATA ports on her motherboard, nothing seems to stop it. Most of the time a couple reboots fixes the issue but that's just a band-aid, I need to fix it permanently.

Anyone got any insight on this issue?

Comment: does the hard drive work on another system? do other hard drives work on that system? Have you swapped power connectors/PSU as well?

Comment: Adding to Journeyman: get into BIOS and see if the drive is detected there.

Comment: Take copy of drive, return under manufacturer's warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything else, back your data up.  It's possible that the problem is not actually with the hard drive, but there's no point in risking data loss.

Also test another hard drive and see if you have the same problem.  Then you'll know if it's the hard drive that's broken, or your PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I rebooted my PC and it told me there was no HD's found.  but in the BIOS my disk controller had switched its self from IDE to RAID mode. So you can switched back and it worked again. this the step to swicth it. go to the BIOS setup, & change the disk controller setting from AHCI to IDE.